# Play Game Services, can we know when we pass another hiscore?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am using Play Game Services, for leaderboards and achievements. Is it possible to know when the player beats one of his friends' highscore? (Like in Candy Crush).
In general, I can't find extensive API documentation for Play Services APIs, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

The general information about Play Game Services is at https://developers.google.com/games/services/.

You should consider developing your own backend server to perform the check of passing a friend since you need to keep track of the relative positions of players over time.

At a high level, the steps would be:

1. Call [Players.loadConnectedPlayers](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players#public-methods).  This will return a list of players that have played your game and that are connected to the current player.  You'll need to send this list of player ids to  the server.
2. Get an auth code from the client using Player. using `Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(googleApiClient, “your_server_client_id”)`.
3. Pass this code to your backend web server application.

Then on the server:

1. List item

   Exchange the auth code for an access token.
2. Use [`Scores.listWindow`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/listWindow) to list the scores around the player's score.
3. Compare the scores of the connected players to the new score.

An optimization would be only do this if the player gets a new high score.